# The left side of my window is cutting off for some reason

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for a friend and for some reason, the right side of the text cuts off when the window is shrunk to its smallest size as well as on phones. I've given the code below.

He wants it to appear so that the shovel image is fixed but it is possible to scroll from right to left for the menu buttons.

this is the website: http://gonetilmonday.com/

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>monday sucks</title>
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="./images/Robbie/gtmFlagLogo.JPG"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="allContent">
      <div class="shovel">
        <div class="overlay">
          <img src="./images/Robbie/stayAlive.png" alt="" class="stayAlive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMediaLinks">
      <a href="https://fanlink.to/gonetilmonday">
        <div class="musicLink"></div>
      </a>
      <a
        href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZ63pdM-KfU&list=PLBj7nXLL_85nmZgnuNGctSzhGmaesPrTJ"
      >
        <div class="youtubeLink"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="mailto: gtm@usa.com">
        <div class="mailLink"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gonetilmonday/">
        <div class="instaLink"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/_gonetilmonday">
        <div class="twitterLink"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is the css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.allContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.shovel {
  width: 150px;
  height: 331px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(../images/Robbie/shovel.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: -95px;
  margin-top: -80px;
}

.overlay {
  width: 110px;
  height: 331px;
  position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  background-image: url(../images/Robbie/stayAlive.png);
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.shovel:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.stayAlive {
  width: 140px;
  height: 92px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}
/* Social Media */
.socialMediaLinks {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: -120px;
}

.musicLink {
  width: 98px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(../images/Robbie/music.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.youtubeLink {
  width: 98px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(../images/Robbie/youtube.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.mailLink {
  width: 98px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(../images/Robbie/mail.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.instaLink {
  width: 98px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(../images/Robbie/insta.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.twitterLink {
  width: 98px;
  height: 51px;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(../images/Robbie/twitter.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like the elements to wrap, so add `flex-wrap:wrap` to their container:

```
.socialMediaLinks {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* <-- Add this line */
  margin-top: -120px;
}
```